# I have to clean every time I update my SDK pod in my swift3 project

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm working with XCode9 and Swift3 and every time I change any file from my SDK `pods`, I have to `clean > run` to see the changes so It takes me a lot of time to make a change in my project.

[this](https://postimg.org/image/14bsfprm17/) is the structure of my project. My podfile has something like [this](http://postimg.org/image/8hr6eoob23)

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: `every time I change any file from pods` You're not supposed to edit the code in the pods. If you do, Xcode has to recompile everything because of the dependencies (this is normal) and you will lose your modifications if/when you update the pods anyway.

Comment: @Moritz so that means that in this structure: https://postimg.org/image/8hr6eoob23/ every time Project is modified XCode has to recompile everything?

Comment: Wait. Your question is unclear. I thought you were editing the pods *themselves* (the code). Looks like actually you're just talking about the pods *list* in Podfile. The answer is still the same: yes, of course, Xcode has to recompile everything when the pods *list* changes, because of dependencies. :)

Comment: I've updated my question since I've realiced it was very unclear

Comment: For me a simple build (Cmd+B) works when I edit any of my development pods